# Scroll to Top script doesn't work - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue:
I added a scroll to top script to my website (developed with Twitter Bootstrap 4v) and it doesn't work. However this script works on the same website which was developed with Bootstrap 3. I think that there's an error occurred with bootstrap version, but unfortunately I can't find the issue.

```
<div class="toTop">
  <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up icons"></i></a>
</div>

$('.toTop').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');         
});
```

Console:

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 smooth.js:2 Uncaught
>   TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at smooth.js:2 (anonymous) @ smooth.js:2

This is a Wordpress theme built by me with Bootstrap 4 framework.
in my case jQuery loads via functions.php with the following code:

```
// include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a JS conflict too.

Try to replace `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

If it's not working please add a **demo link** so I can take a look.